# Debian xfce opens in vim using xfce4-terminal

Tags: xfce, xterm, debian-jessie

I'm using debian jessie. In xfce when I open the right-click menu on text files etc there is an "open in vim". When I click this the file opens in vim but vim is in xterm instead of the xfce terminal (xfce4-terminal).

How to make vim opens in xfce terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Debian provides a configurable *generic* terminal called [`x-terminal-emulator`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html#s11.8.3) (a special [package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/x-terminal-emulator)), which is a symbolic link to a particular terminal emulator.  You can change this using the command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

That will give you a command-line menu allowing you to select a preferred terminal from those which you have already installed.

There are some special cases where `xterm` is used because none of the alternatives provide the given functionality.  But if all you need is a terminal, then Debian policy is to use `x-terminal-emulator` instead of a particular terminal name.  (Occasionally there are bug-reports for cases that have been overlooked).